# Application dead slow sometimes, it get back to normal state only if server is restarted

Tags: java, windows, oracle11g, weblogic12c

My application deployed in the Weblogic instance is dead slow sometimes. I'm using ADF 12c for application development

Weblogic Version: 12.2.1 in Windows Server 2012 R2
JDK version : 1.8-65
Database : Oracle 11g

It get back to normal state once I restart the weblogic server. 
I don't know how to resolve this issue and couldn't yet understood the root cause for this. 
So far, I managed to gather the following details. 
•   At this specific time, Managed server log file shows the following error related to Stuck Threads:

```
<Error> <WebLogicServer> <ManagedServer_1> <[STANDBY] ExecuteThread: '124' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <2c76372a-dbe4-4308-a06c-b9944a2d5d3a-0001b9dc> <1472636531716> <[severity-value: 8] [rid: 0] [partition-id: 0] [partition-name: DOMAIN] > <BEA-000337> <[STUCK] ExecuteThread: '117' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)' has been busy for "630" seconds working on the request "Http Request Information: weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl@714bd487[GET /abcV3/adwwls/wls.ads], which is more than the configured time (StuckThreadMaxTime) of "600" seconds in "server-failure-trigger". Stack trace:
oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.activedata.AdsProcessor.doProcess(AdsProcessor.java:184)
oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.activedata.AdsServlet.doGet(AdsServlet.java:112)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:286)
weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:260)
weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:137)
weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:350)
weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:25)
weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
oracle.adf.library.webapp.LibraryFilter.doFilter(LibraryFilter.java:166)
weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
weblogic.servlet.utils.FastSwapFilter.doFilter(FastSwapFilter.java:64)
weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter$1.run(JpsAbsFilter.java:141)
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
oracle.security.jps.util.JpsSubject.doAsPrivileged(JpsSubject.java:315)
oracle.security.jps.ee.util.JpsPlatformUtil.runJaasMode(JpsPlatformUtil.java:649)
oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.runJaasMode(JpsAbsFilter.java:124)
oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.doFilter(JpsAbsFilter.java:232)
oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsFilter.doFilter(JpsFilter.java:94)
weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
oracle.dms.servlet.DMSServletFilter.doFilter(DMSServletFilter.java:224)
weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestEventsFilter.doFilter(RequestEventsFilter.java:32)
weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3654)
weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3620)
weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:326)
weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAsForUserCode(SecurityManager.java:196)
weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSecurityProvider.runAsForUserCode(WlsSecurityProvider.java:203)
weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:71)
weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2423)
weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2280)
weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2258)
weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.runInternal(ServletRequestImpl.java:1626)
weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1586)
weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:270)
weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:348)
weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:333)
weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:54)
weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41)
weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:617)
weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:397)
weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:346)
>
```

Initially, Max Stuck Thread Time was 600 seconds. But, increasing the stuck threads time did not resolve my issue.

•   I have set the following arguments at server start : 
    -Xms1024m -Xmx4096m -XX:NewRatio=2 -XX:SurvivorRatio=3 -XX:+AggressiveHeap
•   The CPU usage of the server where Database is running :19% (Processes-19%, Services - 15%)
•   The CPU usage of the server where application is running :97% 
•   Coming to the database side, 
    ps_txn table shows the count as : 7608

•   Heap usage : 2228.21
•   Active session : 29

Can anyone please help me in this regard? Any suggestions are most welcome. 
 Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you have a memory leak or other resource problem?

Comment: @ScaryWombat The question isn't "do you have a memory leak or other resource problem." It's WHERE is the memory leak?

Comment: @mttdbrd Sorry I can not tell from the above whether it is a memory leak or other type of resource leak.  Feel free to answer this question or ask your own questions for the OP

Comment: @scarywombat Sorry, was trying to be funny. It's a clear memory leak. I'm guessing holding open to many DB connections or not returning them to the pool.

Comment: @akr You need to produce a minimum viable sample that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @mttdbrd Yes, the usual suspects.   Sorry for not detecting your humour.

Comment: We see exactly the same symptoms on an application that ran beautifully on 12.1.3. Upgrading the code to 12.2.1.2.0 - without any chances on our code, did it.